# Can I Host a WPF user control in a win form user control in a WPF window?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I was wondering if you could host a WPF user control in a windows form and this form again in a WPF window. I tried this out and it seems to be working.

The question is if this is recommended and if there are any disadvantages or anything that would not work as expected?

Comment: "The question is if this is recommended" - of course not. "there are any disadvantages or anything that would not work as expected" - yes, there are some. they are described in the documentation

Comment: Which Documentation? Do you have a link?